# Update All a whole column with one new value

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table called Product and I want to update the column in the table called price and the table has 100 different Items and I want to change the price in all 100 to request.I must be missing part of it. And the table is able to hold letters as well so that is not the issue.

```
UPDATE Product
SET Price = request;
```

Comment: ,Post your sample data and expected output...

Comment: What is `request`? Is it meant to be a string? If so... `SET Price = 'request'`

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to letter cases. In a non-Windows MySQL server, table names and columns are case-sensitive. For example `price` instead of `Price`, `product` instead of `Product` depending on what is on the server. But in Windows all these are fine.

Also if you are in SQL strict mode UPDATE always requires you to put a WHERE clause where primary key should be involved.

Answer (score 0):

Go for this:

```
UPDATE Product
SET Price = 'request';
```

`String` must be written within the quotes while updating any column.